# Masking a field in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, input, masking

I need to mask the field  so they are not visible after entering .
having SSN  of 10 digit (123-123-1234). I need to mask in such a way that (xxx-xxx-1234). Also While submit the page I need to send original variable (123-123-1234) to service.
I used Cleave ,and tried with react-input-mask too. 
Any help would be appreciated.

```
    let enrollmentInput
    if (formatted) {
      enrollmentInput = (
        <Cleave key={refName} htmlRef={(ref) => this.refs[refName] = ref}
          className={inputClassNames}
          options={options}
          placeholder={placeholder}
          type={type}
          value={this.props.user[refName]}
        />
      )
    } 
    return 

          <InputMask {...enrollmentInput}  maskChar=" " maskType='ssn'className='control'/>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Once you detect the value in the `input` field is valid, you can copy the existing value and save it in your components state (`this.state`). Then replace the value inside the `input` element by the masked value. Finally use the value you picked before to send the form

As an example you could do the following:

```js
class HiddenSsnInput extends Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            validSsnEntered: false,
            ssnValue: undefined,
        };
        this._onBlur = this._onBlur.bind(this);
    }

    isValid() {
        return this.state.validSsnEntered;
    }

    value() {
        return this.state.ssnValue;
    }

    _onBlur() {
        const entered = this.refs.ssnInput.value;
        if (isValidSsn(entered) ) { // Implement yourself
            this.setState({validSsnEntered: true, ssnValue: entered});
            // Clear the value in the input
            this.refs.ssnInput.value = maskedSsnInput(entered); // implement yourself
        } else {
            this.setState({validSsnEntered: false, ssnValue: undefined});
        }
    }

    render() {
        return <input ref={(ref) => this.refs.ssnInput} onBlur={this._onBlur} />;
    }
}
```

A parent component can simply grab the value and validity of the SSN while the component does not have to show the actual value to the user after entering.

*Typed the code without any checking, so beware of typos*

Comment: There are obviously a lot of ways to solve this, but I like this one, because it solves OP's question of "how to do it in React."

Comment: @user9074131 The basic idea of the answer here is to use the state of the component to store the variable, and display it through render() in a way that hides it, but can still submit it.  Like all code, though, you can abstract out the changes much further.  I know of no plugins whose setup is simpler than just abstracting out your logic.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to display only the last 4 digits, why not only taking the last 4 char of the string and hardcoding the Xs?

```
handleChange(event) {
  this.setState({fieldValue: event.target.value});
}

<input 
  type="text" 
  value={'xxx-xxx-' + this.state.fieldValue.substr(this.state.fieldValue.length - 4)}
  onChange={this.handleChanges} />
```

This way, you will be able to send `this.state.fieldValue` to the service.

Comment: Props are frozen and unchangeable.  I suspect that if it's a form, it starts out blank and expects something to change.

Comment: @HoldOffHunger Yes Exactly ,Its a form and starts out blank.

Comment: @Vincent I'm afraid its just sending  xxx-xxx to service.

Comment: I changed my code example to a clearer version. It's just a different approach. What I meant to say is instead of using a mask library, why not displaying only the last 4 char of the inputted value?

Answer (score 0):

I ran into similar issues as the OP and ended up creating a custom SSN component to take care of most it:

https://codesandbox.io/s/64qpz795on

I wanted to mask the input while typing. 
I wanted to option to display last 4 as digits instead of hidden by asterisks.

The rest of the app is using redux-form and material-ui. You'll see the redux change call in there to update redux store. I just styled my custom input to match the way I have most the other forms inputs.